# Seaborn displot with two y axes

Tags: python, seaborn

How do I create a histogram using Seaborn's displot with two y axes: one showing count and the other showing the corresponding density? I tried this code but the result does not make sense:

```
ax = sns.distplot( df_flavors.Freq, kde = False )
ax.set_title( 'Distribution of Flavor Purchases\nNumber Purchased', fontsize = font_title )
ax.set( ylabel = 'Count', xlabel = 'Number of Flavors Purchased' )
ax.set_xticks( range( n ))
ax.set_xticklabels( range( n ) )
##
ax2 = plt.twinx()
```

The DataFrame df_flavors is a large DataFrame with 2000 records, each showing how many different flavors of yogurts people bought (0 - 7 flavors).  The people are respondents to a survey with n = 2000.  The variable Freq is the count for each respondent. The sns.distplot produces the count on the left axis; that's ok.  The ax2 = plt.twinx() produces a second y-axis but not percents on that axis, just cumulative percents; that's not ok.  Any suggestions for getting just percent or density of the total 2000 on the right?

Comment: where's the rest of the code? What are you plotting on ax2?

Comment: This seems to be the relevant code.  The rest in my Jupyter code cell just creates the DataFrame.  The good question is what's being plotted on ax2.  This is the part I don't know.  I'm not sure from what I can find what this is doing.  I just want the percent of the total respondents for each number of flavors selected.

Answer (score 1):

On one axis, the histogram without the kde could be drawn. And on the other the kde without the histogram. The left y-axis will contain the count and the right the density.

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# generate some random test data
y = np.abs(np.random.normal(np.random.choice([5, 9, 15], 2000, p=[3/9, 5/9, 1/9]), 2, 2000))

ax = sns.distplot(y, kde=False)
ax.set_title('Distribution of Flavor Purchases\nNumber Purchased')
ax.set(ylabel='Count', xlabel='Number of Flavors Purchased')
n = 20
ax.set_xticks(range(n))
ax.set_xticklabels(range(n))

ax2 = plt.twinx()
ax2 = sns.distplot(y, kde=True, hist=False, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylabel('density')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]